# Windows 10 creating multiple NetBIOS sessions to Microsoft

Tags: windows-10, firewall, netbios

I apologize if this question has already been answered, and if this is a dumb question, please be gentle. I am having difficulties trying to find a good explanation to this.

I was going thru my firewall just now, and I am noticing multiple NetBIOS sessions from my Windows 10 Pro computer to IP Addresses that are owned by Microsoft. Why would Windows 10 need to establish NetBIOS connections to Microsoft? Has anyone had any experience with this? My machine is not part of a Active Directory Domain or anything like that; it is simple Windows 10 Pro installation.

Comment: On the face of it, there can be no NetBIOS sessions outside of your local network, so we need some more information about these sessions and their target IP addresses.